In Node Express Todo App Troubleshooting Failed Jest Test Cases in CRUD Operations having response.body undefined
I am trying to get some test cases passed in node, express application. No matter what i try,  2 test cases are being failed, which are

Update Task › Update a task 1
Get task by ID › the taskName should be updated

It's a simple todo app CRUD and test cases are written in jest. test cases are being failed because i am getting response.body undefined
Challenge is
During this challenge you will be building on an empty Express Js server and adding the necessary changes for it to become a functional todo list program.
There is a list in index.js called taskList you will use it to store the task objects.
the server has the following routes:
this is what a task looks like:
{
taskName: "string"
status: "string"
created: 'string'
}

get / root of the server, returns "Hello world"

post /task takes a task in the body creates a uuid and saves it like the following in the tasklist
{
    uuid: {
        taskName: "string", status:
        "string", created: "string"
    }
}

GET /tasks Returns all the tasks in a list:
[{UUID: {}}, {UUID:{}}] in a list:

* GET /task/:id 

Returns the task that belongs to the id sent in the path if it exists, otherwise returns null. 
The response structure should be as follows: 
{
    uuid: {
        taskName: "string", 
        status: "string", 
        created:"string" 
    }
}
The response code should be 204. 

PATCH /task/:id

Updates a task by id if it exists in the database, the request body 
will have the keys you need to update in the task object. 
The response code should be 204.

DELETE /task/:id 

Deletes a task from the list if the id exists in the list, otherwise return null. 
The response code should be 204. 

Note: schema.js in the folder models has a schema object of the request, you can use AJV to validate the request body

I tried sending response as an whole object but i always get undefined in response.body.taskName

Here's the index.test.js
const { expect } = require("@jest/globals");
const request = require("supertest");
const fs = require("fs");
const { validate: validateUUID } = require("uuid");

class test_class {
  constructor() {
    this.test_result = {};
    this.test_count = 0;
  }
  update_report(stdin, stdout, out, display_name = "") {
    let key = "test" + String(this.test_count);
    let test_case = {
      in: `${stdin}`,
      expected: `${stdout}`,
      actual: `${out}`,
      passed: out === stdout,
      display_name: display_name,
    };
    this.test_result[key] = test_case;
    this.test_count++;
  }

  
  writeFile() {
    var testObject = this.test_result;
    fs.writeFileSync(
      "./test_report.json",
      JSON.stringify(testObject, null, 4),
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}

function isValidUUID(inputString) {
  return validateUUID(inputString);
}


const task = {
  taskName: "Test Task",
  status: "In progress",
  created: "2022-02-14T11:07:05",
};


const update_task = {
  taskName: "new Task",
};

const test_client = new test_class();
let task_id;

const app = require("./index");

describe("Get request to the root", () => {
  test("the response should be ok", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get("/");
    test_client.update_report("/", "Hello World!", response.text);
    test_client.writeFile();
    expect(response.text).toBe("Hello World!");
  });
});

describe("Create new task", () => {
  test("the returned task id should be a valid uuid", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).post("/task").send(task);
    test_client.update_report("/task", 200, response.statusCode);
    test_client.writeFile();
    // Extract the task ID from the response body
    task_id = response.text; // Use response.text instead of response.body.id

    // Check if the returned ID is a valid UUID
    test_client.update_report(
      "No input for this test",
      true,
      validateUUID(task_id),
      `Check if the returned ID is a valid UUID but recived ${task_id}`
    );
    test_client.writeFile();

    // Assertions
    expect(validateUUID(task_id)).toBe(true);
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});

describe("Get task by ID", () => {
  console.log("Get task by ID 0");
  test("the returned task should contain the right taskName", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get(`/task/${task_id}`);
    test_client.update_report(`/task/${task_id}`, 200, response.statusCode);
    test_client.update_report(`/task/${task_id}`, task.taskName, response.text);
    test_client.writeFile();
    expect(response.text).toEqual(task.taskName);
  });
});

describe("Get All Tasks", () => {
  test("should return an array with the length of ", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get(`/tasks`);
    test_client.update_report(`/tasks`, 200, response.statusCode);
    test_client.update_report(`/task/${task_id}`, 1, response.body.length);
    test_client.writeFile();
    expect(1).toEqual(response.body.length);
  });
});

describe("Update Task", () => {
  test("Update a task 1", async () => {
    const response = await request(app)
      .patch(`/task/${task_id}`)
      .send(update_task);
    test_client.update_report(`/task/${task_id}`, 204, response.statusCode);
    test_client.writeFile();
    expect(response.body.taskName).toEqual(task.taskName);
  });
});

describe("Get task by ID", () => {
  test("the taskName should be updated", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get(`/task/${task_id}`);
    test_client.update_report(`/task/${task_id}`, 200, response.statusCode);
    test_client.update_report(
      `/task/${task_id}`,
      update_task.taskName,
      response.body.taskName
    );
    test_client.writeFile();
    expect(response.body.taskName).toEqual(update_task.taskName);
  });
});

describe("Get task by ID", () => {
  test("the taskName should be updated", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).delete(`/task/${task_id}`);
    test_client.update_report(`/task/${task_id}`, 204, response.statusCode);
    test_client.writeFile();
    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(204);
  });
});

Here's index.js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { v4: uuidv4, validate: validateUUID } = require('uuid');
const Ajv = require("ajv");
const taskSchema = require("./models/schema");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let taskList = [];

// Create an AJV instance and compile the schema
const ajv = new Ajv();
const validateTask = ajv.compile(taskSchema);


// GET / (root of the server)
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

// POST /task - Create a new task
app.post('/task', (req, res) => {
  const task = req.body;
  // Validate the request body against the schema
  const valid = validateTask(task);
  if (!valid) {
    return res.status(400).send(validateTask.errors);
  }

  const taskId = uuidv4();

  taskList.push({ [taskId]: { ...task, uuid: taskId } });
  res.status(200).send(taskId);
});

// GET /tasks - Retrieve all tasks
app.get('/tasks', (req, res) => {
  res.send(taskList);
});


// GET /task/:id - Retrieve a specific task by ID
app.get('/task/:id', (req, res) => {
  const taskId = req.params.id;
  const index = taskList.findIndex(task => task[taskId]);
  if (index !== -1) {
    res.status(200).send(taskList[index][taskId].taskName);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(204);
  }
});

// // PATCH /task/:id - Update a specific task by ID
app.patch('/task/:id', (req, res) => {
  const taskId = req.params.id;
  const update = req.body.taskName;

  // Validate the request body against the schema
  const valid = validateTask(update);
  if (!valid) {
    return res.status(400).send(validateTask.errors);
  }

  // Find the task in taskList based on taskId
  const index =  taskList.findIndex(task => task[taskId])
  if (index !== -1) {
    
    taskList[index][taskId] = { ...taskList[index][taskId], taskName: update };

    // Send the updated task name in the response body
    res.status(200).send(taskList[index][taskId]);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404); // Not Found if task with given ID doesn't exist
  }
});

// DELETE /task/:id - Delete a specific task by ID
app.delete('/task/:id', (req, res) => {
  // console.log("6");

  const taskId = req.params.id;
  const index = taskList.findIndex(task => task[taskId]);
  if (index !== -1) {
    taskList.splice(index, 1);
    res.sendStatus(204).send(taskList[index]);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(204);
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;

schema.js
const task = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
        taskName: {type: "string"},
        status: {type: "string"},
        created: {type: "string"}
    },
    required: ["taskName", "status", "created"],
    additionalProperties: false
}

package.json
{
    "name": "express-js-1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
            "ajv": "^8.12.0",
            "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
            "express": "^4.17.1",
            "jest": "^27.0.6",
            "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
            "superagent": "^6.1.0",
            "supertest": "^6.1.3",
            "uuid": "^9.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
            "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
            "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10"
    },
    "scripts": {
            "test": "jest --watchAll=false  --forceExit",
            "start": "nodemon index.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}


There are two separate problems to address:
In 'Update Task - Update a task 1' you are comparing a changed task to the previous version of the task. Change the expect statement to
expect(response.body.taskName).toEqual(update_task.taskName);

In 'Get task by ID - the taskName should be updated' your test is because you are trying to index into the taskName property when your GET method already returns the taskName property. I suggest changing the GET /task/:id method to:
app.get('/task/:id', (req, res) => {
  const taskId = req.params.id;
  const index = taskList.findIndex(task => task[taskId]);
  if (index !== -1) {
    res.status(200).send(taskList[index][taskId]);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(204);
  }
});

Just be careful, you'll need to update the first 'Get task by ID' test to expect the whole task object, not just the taskName. If you really want to just return the task name, you can edit the failing in test as such:
expect(response.body).toEqual(update_task.taskName);

